# Finding a newline in the csv file

Tags: bash, perl, csv, unix

I know there are a lot of questions about this (latest one [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222049/how-to-detect-and-remove-newline-character-within-a-column-in-a-csv-file).), but almost all of them are how to join those broken lines into one from a csv file or remove them. I don't want to remove, but I just want to display/find that line (or probably the line number?)

Example data:

```
22224,across,some,text,0,,,4 etc
33448,more,text,1,,3,,,4 etc
abcde,text,number,444444,0,1,,,, etc
358890,more
,text,here,44,,,, etc
abcdefg,textds3,numberss,413,0,,,,, etc
985678,93838,text,,,,
,text,continuing,from,previous,line,,, etc
```

More search on this, and I know I shouldn't use `bash` to accomplish this, but rather shoud use `perl`. I tried (from various website, I don't know perl), but apparently I don't have the `Text::CSV` package and I don't have permission to install one.

As I told I have no idea how to even start looking for this, so I don't have any script. This is `not` a windows file, this is very much `unix` file so we can ignore the `CR` problem.

Desired output:

```
358890,more
,text,here,44,,,, etc
985678,93838,text,,,,
,text,continuing,from,previous,line,,, etc
```

or

```
Line 4: 358890,more
,text,here,44,,,, etc 

Line 7: 985678,93838,text,,,,
,text,continuing,from,previous,line,,, etc
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: How are you determining where one record starts and ends? Do they all have the same number of fields?

Comment: @123 Yes, they have the same number of fields, field separator is `,`. But the thing is, I don't know how many fields are there. I can find this using the header of the file, correct?

Comment: We don't know, it depends. An RFC-4180 compliant CSV should have one record by line, yours doesn't so we can't really make any assumption

Comment: Maybe you can infer other rules from looking at the file. Does every line starting with a number mark the start of a new record? Do only line starting with a comma mark the continuation of a current record?

Comment: Assuming same amount of fields per records `perl -ne 'if(tr/,/,/<7){$line=$.;while(tr/,/,/<7){$_.=<>}print "Line $line: $_\n"}' file` would probs work. Multiline fields should be quoted though, so you probably won't be able to use packages since your csv is non compliant

Comment: In your example, almost every "record" has a different number of fields. Are you sure you're giving us a representative sample of your data?

Comment: @123 Worked like a charm! My file had 29 fields, so I changed the `7` from your command and updated it to 28 and it found the line number where the file breaks! Please post this as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @randomir Apologize, I was just too lazy to count the fields. I would be more diligent in providing the right details.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks! I did try to find a pattern, but sometimes the record starts with a number, sometimes with text. But as you mentioned, `,` starting a line was the culprit as far as I noted. I have to check this for multiple files, so some may just start like a normal (like having a new line in the comment/remarks field). 123's solutions worked well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use perl to count the number of fields(commas), and append the next line until it reaches the correct number

```
perl -ne 'if(tr/,/,/<28){$line=$.;while(tr/,/,/<28){$_.=<>}print "Line $line: $_\n"}' file
```

Comment: Gotta love `perl`. :)

Answer (score 1):

I do love `Perl` but I don't think it is the best tool for this job.

If you want a report of all lines that DO NOT have exactly the correct number of commas/delimiters, you could use the unix language `awk`.

For example, this command:

```
/usr/bin/awk -F , 'NF != 8' < csv_file.txt
```

will print all lines that DO NOT have exactly `7 commas`.  Comma is specified as the Field with `-F` and the Number of Fields is specified with `NF`.

Comment: This would run into a problem with lines that have quoted text that contains commas.

Comment: A good thought. The field separator can be a regular expression rather than a single character. If any delimiters (commas) occur in the text, they would need to be escaped and the regular expression could account for the escape character.

Comment: @TRowe Interesting. I use `awk` sometimes though I'm still a learner. I didn't think of it like this, but the logic makes sense. I haven't fully checked all my files, but if one of them has a comma in a quoted text, we'll see how this turns out. But still 123's answer has one edge over yours - printing line number. Can this also be done via `awk`?

Comment: `NR` numbers:
`awk -F , 'NF != 8 {print NR, $0}' < csv_file.txt`

Comment: Let me check this tomorrow. :)